# How can I assign a value from OptionMenu (tkinter) to use it later?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am totally new to Python and trying to create a program (using tkinter) that converts units. I think I have a problem in the 5th line. Can anyone examine my codes and give me some suggestion to fix it? Thank you

```
choices = {'feet': 0.3048,  'inches': 0.0254}
choice = StringVar()
popupChoice = OptionMenu(secondFrame, choice, *choices)
popupChoice.pack()
pick_choice = choices[choice.get()]

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        meter.set(value*float(pick_choice))
    except ValueError:
        print("error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringVar() as default provides you empty string ' ', so nothing can be reached in your dictionary and KeyError is raised. Simple If should do it.

```
# choices.keys() will provide list of your keys in dictionary 
if choice.get() in choices.keys():
    pick_choice = choices[choice.get()]
```

Or you can set default value before it, for example:

```
choice = StringVar()
choice.set("feet")
```

Example, how it can look:

```
from tkinter import *

def calculate():
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        label.config(text=str(value*float(choices[choice.get()])))
    except ValueError or KeyError:
        label.config(text='wrong/missing input') 
# config can change text and other in widgets

secondFrame = Tk()
# entry for value
feet = StringVar()
e = Entry(secondFrame, textvariable=feet)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5) # grid is more useful for more customization
# label showing result or other text
label = Label(secondFrame, text=0)
label.grid(row=0, column=2)
# option menu
choices = {'feet': 0.3048,  'inches': 0.0254}
choice = StringVar()
choice.set("feet")  # default value, to use value: choice.get()
popupChoice = OptionMenu(secondFrame, choice, *choices)
popupChoice.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
# button to launch conversion, calculate is not called with variables
# call them in function, or use lambda function - command=lambda: calculate(...)
button1 = Button(secondFrame, command=calculate, text='convert')
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
secondFrame.mainloop()
```

Comment: if my code continue with this code below, it will show "pick_choice" is not defined:
    
 def calculate(*args):
    
try:
 
        value = float(feet.get())

        meter.set(value*float(pick_choice))

    except ValueError:

        print("error")

Comment: It is because tkinter is running in loop and you dont want call your values immediately, because they dont need to be defined if you use user inputs. Better is to define it, when you need it, so in the calculate function. See example and I hope, this will solve all the problems.